# How do I reset master and keep my branch in git?

Tags: git, git-reset

Suppose I do

```
$ git checkout master
$ touch foo.py
$ git commit -m "oops" foo.py
$ git checkout -b new_branch
$ touch bar.py
$ git commit -m "changes" bar.py
```

Now when I try to push back changes on new_branch, I get

```
Local branch 'master' is ahead of remote branch 'origin/master'
```

How do I reset master while not losing my changes (foo.py, bar.py) on new_branch?

I read the [git reset page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html), and it looked like it might involve --keep, but I couldn't tell.

Comment: Do you mean you want reset your local master branch so it is no longer ahead of origin/master?

Comment: @Chrs yes, correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be very confusing initially, and what you needed was a proper introduction to how Git implements branches; but at this point we'll use the retrofit method. :-)  The trick to understanding all this is that Git's *commits* are permanent and unchanging, but its *branches*—or more precisely, branch *names*—are temporary, and in fact mostly irrelevant.

There are three things that matter when you are building a *new* commit (they are `HEAD`, the *index*, and the *work-tree*), but once you have the commit built and committed, it's quite permanent and it is very hard to get Git to lose it entirely.  It's easy enough to accidentally misplace it, though, so let's try to avoid that. :-)

If we ignore the branch names entirely, we can draw a *graph* of the commits that exist in your repository.  Given what you have done—making two new commits—let's draw them like this, where round `o`s represent commits, and `A` and `B` are your two *new* commits:

```
...--o--o--o
            \
             A
              \
               B
```

We could draw them all on one line, but I want to leave room to write labels in on the right.  Commit `A` is your "oops", and `B` is your "changes".

The main noteworthy thing about this graph drawing is that each commit *points to* (stores the hash ID of) its predecessor commit.  This means that commit `B` points back to commit `A`.  Commit `A` points back to the next-most-recent commit, which points back still further, and so on.

Now we add the labels—the *branch names*.  The last boring commit `o` still probably has a label `origin/master`.  Commit `A` has the label `master`, and commit `B` has the label `new_branch`, so let's draw these in:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- origin/master
            \
             A   <-- master
              \
               B   <-- new_branch (HEAD)
```

This is what branch names are and do for you: they are pointers to commits; they remember each commit's big ugly hash ID for you.

When you are on some branch and make a *new* commit, the branch *name* comes along for the ride.  The special name `HEAD` remembers which branch you're on, so that Git knows which name to *move* to the new commit.  (We needed this temporarily at least, when `master` and `new_branch` briefly both pointed to commit `A`.)

What you want to do now is move `master` *back* to point to the last of the boring `o` commits.  To do so, you can use `git reset`, which lets you move a name in an arbitrary way:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This **assumes** (see final section below) that `origin/master` really *does* point to the last of the boring `o` commits.  The `git reset --hard` says: *Wipe out my current index and work-tree, and move my current branch—according to `HEAD`—so that it points to the commit I name here.*  We must `git checkout master` *first*, so that `HEAD` names `master`.  Then the `git reset` does this:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
            \
             A
              \
               B   <-- new_branch
```

So now your two new commits `A` and `B` are found only via `new_branch` and not via `master`.

(There are several more things that branch names do for you.  In particular, they *protect* commits from being removed by Git's "garbage collector".  If a commit has any name by which we can find it, it's protected.  If it has *no* name, it's no longer protected.  There are some semi-hidden names that protect everything for a while—at least 30 days by default—to make sure commits don't get trashed accidentally, but finding them through these *reflog* names is annoying, so we try not to rely on it so much.

The branch names are also used for `git push`, so there they matter a fair bit.)

(I mention "trashing" the index and work-tree above, which isn't completely true.  The `git reset` command, used the way we're using it here, has three jobs it can do:

- move the current branch
- reset the index
- reset the work-tree

It always does the first, optionally *adds* the second job, and then optionally *adds* the third.  The `--hard` mode does all three, the `--mixed` mode does the first two, and the `--soft` mode does only one.  To understand them all properly, we would have to look closely at the definitions of *index* and *work-tree* and I'll leave that for other SO questions/answers.  The key item here, though, is that you *don't* want to `git reset --hard` until you have everything saved away in commits.)

#### What if there's no `origin/master` (or it points back too far)?

We assumed, above, that there was a handy label—a so-called *remote-tracking branch*—identifying the commit we want to `git reset` our `master` to point-to.  If we don't have this label, or it points to an even earlier commit, we must locate that commit some other way.

There are a lot of ways to do this.  The most straightforward is to go by its hash ID.  If you run `git log` while on some branch, you see each commit that is "on" or "contained in" that branch, normally in Git's usual backwards-going order.  For instance, we might `git log` and see commit `B`, with its big ugly hash ID, then commit `A` with its hash ID, and then that boring commit `o` with its big ugly hash ID.

We can use the raw hash ID:

```
git checkout master && git reset --hard <hash-id>
```

if we don't have the label.  If we do have the label, we should probably just use it.

You might remember to get help from "A DOG" with `git log`:

```
git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
```

The **a**ll makes Git show all branches and all remote-tracking branches (and everything else: tags, the "stash", notes, etc).  The **d**ecorate option attaches the label names to commits.  The **o**neline option makes the output show just one line for each commit, and the **g**raph option makes Git try to draw the commit graph.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer. I didn't test it because I solved my problem another (more hacky) way, but this is what I wanted.

Comment: @torek, Nice explanation, that branches have nothing to do with commits, I wonder why doesn't any git guide explain it that way. Is it novel or did you see it explained like this somewhere else?

Comment: @Pacerier: it's not that they are completely irrelevant: branch names let us (and Git) *find* specific commits. But once the commits are *found*, the names don't matter any more: those commits that are found find any previous commits. We only need the branch names to find the *last* commit, and to do that, Git actually *defines* the "last" commit as "the one to which the name points".

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where this formulation comes from. I use it, and [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) uses it. The trick is to emphasize it just enough, but not too much.

Answer (score 0):

How do I reset master while not losing my changes (foo.py, bar.py) on new_branch?

> Yes, foo.py and bar.py is in your new branch.

- You have created a branch from the master which is not pushed to the origin. so when you try to push the master you got the error because its ahead of remote.
- You get that message because you made changes in your local master and you didn't push them to remote.

**You have several ways to "solve" it and it normally depends on how your workflow looks like:**

- In a good workflow your remote copy of master should be the good one while your local copy of master is just a copy of the one in remote. Using this workflow you'll never get this message again.
- If you work in another way and your local changes should be pushed then just git push origin assuming origin is your remote

**How I will be doing it :**

```
git checkout master
git create -b la_lalalla
touch foo.py bar.py
git add drama.py bar.py
git commit -m "Drama commit"
```

merge the branch to your master, this depends on you to do merge or do rebase, then,

```
git push origin master.
```

your done with adding two files to origin/master.

Comment: This is just redoing all the changes again, and ignores new_branch entirely. But in reality I had 50 files in my commit, some new, some changed. I did not wish to re-execute all of the changes carefully, I wanted to use the information on new_branch.